# $("#id option").hide(); not working on safari/chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, safari

Same for:

```
$("#id option").show();
```

I'm just surprised. I thought that something went wrong with my code. I tried it with a blank html:

```
<select id = "name">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
​$("#name option").hide();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kgLkt/

It works like a charm with firefox, but not on safari nor chrome!

Is there a substitute?!

EDIT:
I need to hide/show the option (or some of them) from appearing in the  list.

Comment: Try using a a class instead of id.

Comment: I'm just curios what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why not just hide the select element? I would actually say that the WebKit browsers are doing nothing wrong. And please, please, it's JavaScript not Java.

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is broken.  Make sure to click "save" before copying the link.

Comment: @Daff I'm trying to make an interactive application in which the user will filter his selections based on former choices. After working and testing on firefox I was shocked it did't work on webkit browsers even though it's basic jQuery. I thought I might be missing something.

Comment: The problem is that the options actually are hidden in this case. The select itself is displaying its value. You can verify this with firebug or chrome dev tools. You have to either hide and temporarily set the selected index to -1 or actually remove the HTML.

Comment: @KhaledMahmoud Then I actually think that Diegos solution works best. It would probably make even more sense to keep the list as a JavaScript array or object that you filter and render into the select element afterwards.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**To hide:**

```
var myOpts = $("#id option").detach();
```

**To show:**

```
$("#id option").append(myOpts);
```

As opposed to `.remove()`, `.detach()` keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements.

Answer (score 0):

With the standard select I don't think there is any cross browser way to hide a select option.

You could look for a custom select control or you could keep the full list of items on a separated variable and remove / add items from the select as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Could be an implementation issue...

Perhaps try

```
$("#name option").remove();
```

if you need to maintain some knowledge of what has been removed then load them into a variable before hand.

```
var $opts = $("#name option");
```

you could then use index to add them back in:

```
$("#name").append( $opts.eq(n) );
```

Answer (score -2):

This will work on safari

```
   var select = $('#name');
    var diff = 0;
    console.dir(select[0].options);
    select.find('option').each(function(x) {
        select[0].options[x+diff] = null;
        diff -= 1;
    });
```

Comment: $(#name).css('display','none'); // work well but with option param it doesn't

Comment: Pretty sure .hide is just setting display to none.

Answer (score -2):

You didn't select jQuery in the fiddle. Anyhow, you need to set `selectedIndex` of the `<select>` to `-1` to clear the currently selected option: http://jsfiddle.net/kgLkt/2/.

```
$("#name option").hide().parent().prop("selectedIndex", -1);​​​​​​
```

Comment: I want to hide the option from appearing in the list, and not hiding the default option.

Comment: Well... then I don't know what you're after. The fiddle in my comment shows the default option but hides it from the list.

Comment: No, it doesn't your fiddle doesn't hide. At least, it didn't work with me !!

Comment: @Khaled Mahmoud: Are you using Chrome 17?

Comment: yes 17. Mac version if it would make a difference. and it DID NOT work with me. your fiddle worked only with firefox!