# hide / show option when radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, safari

I want to show an option when the third radio button is clicked. And hide it again when the visitor selects another radio button.

I got the following html-markup for my radio buttons and select element:

```
<p class="input-group input-radio input-field-workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur">
  <label for="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur">
    Wenst u een factuur?
  </label>
  <span class="input-group">
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Ik heb geen factuur nodig." checked="checked" type="radio">
      Ik heb geen factuur nodig.<br>
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Ik heb wel een factuur nodig." type="radio">
      Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.<br>
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Mijn werkgever zal betalen." type="radio">
      Mijn werkgever zal betalen.<br>
  </span>
</p>

<p id="em-booking-gateway" class="em-booking-gateway" style="display: block;">
  <label>Betaal met</label>
  <select name="gateway">
    <option value="idealcheckoutcreditcard">Creditcard</option>
    <option value="idealcheckoutminitix">Werkgever betaalt</option>
    <option value="idealcheckoutmistercash">MisterCash</option>
    <option value="idealcheckoutpaypal">PayPal</option>
    <option value="idealcheckoutmastercard">Mastercard</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

In my css I have done this:

```
.idealcheckoutminitix {
  display: none;
}
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
(function($) {
  $('input[value="Ik heb geen factuur nodig."]').attr('checked',true);
  $(".em-booking-gateway").css('display', 'block');
  $("input[name='workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur']").click(function () {
    $("option[value='idealcheckoutminitix']").css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Mijn werkgever zal betalen.') ? 'block' : 'none');
  })
})(jQuery);
```

This works just fine in `Firefox` but doesn't in `Safari`. I know `Safari` doesn't allow display none on option element but is there any way that I can work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all browsers:-

```js
(function($) {
  var myOpts = $("option[value='idealcheckoutminitix']").detach();//initially disable the setion of option
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){//radio button click event
    if ($('input[type="radio"]:last').is(':checked')) { //when third radio button is checked
      $('select[name="gateway"]').append(myOpts);
    }else {
        myOpts.detach();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="input-group input-radio input-field-workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur">
 <label for="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur">Wenst u een factuur?</label>
 <br>
 <span class="input-group">
  <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Ik heb geen factuur nodig." checked="checked" type="radio">
    Ik heb geen factuur nodig.<br>
  <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Ik heb wel een factuur nodig." type="radio">
    Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.<br>
  <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Mijn werkgever zal betalen." type="radio">
    Mijn werkgever zal betalen.<br>
 </span>
</p>

<p id="em-booking-gateway" class="em-booking-gateway">
 <label>Betaal met</label>
 <br>
 <select name="gateway">
  <option value="idealcheckoutcreditcard">Creditcard</option>
  <option value="idealcheckoutminitix">Werkgever betaalt</option>
  <option value="idealcheckoutmistercash">MisterCash</option>
  <option value="idealcheckoutpaypal">PayPal</option>
  <option value="idealcheckoutmastercard">Mastercard</option>
 </select>
</p>
```

Reference:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813212/4248328

Comment: Sorry for my late replying... This worked perfectly for me, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is disable the option

```
$("option[value='idealcheckoutminitix']").prop('disabled', true);
```

and enable it again when allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Intead of using `display: none`, use the jquery show/hide.

On load you hide the option:

```
$(function(){
    $("option[value='idealcheckoutminitix']").hide();
});
```

Then use your code to show it when the third radio button is selected:

```
$("input[name='workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur']").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        //Verify if is checked
        $("option[value='idealcheckoutminitix']").show();
    }
    else {
        //When not checked, hide again
        $("option[value='idealcheckoutminitix']").hide();
    }
});
```